# Match two columns in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, match

I have two columns in dataframe df

```
  ID      Name
AXD2     SAM S
AXD2       SAM
SCA4       JIM
SCA4 JIM JONES
ASCQ      JOHN
```

I need the output to get a unique id and should match the first name only,

```
  ID  Name
AXD2 SAM S
SCA4   JIM
ASCQ  JOHN
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverlow! What have you tried so far? Could you post your code you have tried?

Comment: Why does AXD2 have SAM S while SCA4 only has JIM?

Comment: Thats the point I only need to match first record from the name column.

Comment: In fact you want to keep the first row of each ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `drop_duplicates`:

```
out = df.drop_duplicates('ID', ignore_index=True)
print(out)

# Output
     ID   Name
0  AXD2  SAM S
1  SCA4    JIM
2  ASCQ   JOHN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby` with `agg` and get `first` of `Name`

```
df.groupby(['ID']).agg(first_name=('Name', 'first')).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cumcount() to find the first iteration name of the ID

```
df['RN'] = df.groupby(['ID']).cumcount() + 1
df = df.loc[df['RN'] == 1]
df[['ID', 'Name']]
```